# Perspective Equations for x,y in image plane?

Tags: matrices, triangles, plane-geometry

I have been trying to figure out how to go about answering this question however I just cannot seem to wrap my head around it.

"Using similar triangle arguments, give the perspective equations for $x$ and $y$ when the image
plane is at $z=0$, the camera position (the focal point) is at $d$, the camera is looking out the
negative $z$ axis, and the point is at $(X,Y,Z)$. Once you have the equations, then put them into
homogenous matrix that gives $(x,y,0) = M  (X,Y,Z).$ "

[image: Included Image to explain question]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this diagram will make it a bit easier to work out the proportions.

[image: Image Plane]

Notice that from similar triangles we obtain the proportions:

\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{d}=\frac{X}{d-Z}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{y}{d}=\frac{Y}{d-Z}
\end{equation}

Thus

\begin{equation}
x=\frac{d}{d-Z}X
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
y=\frac{d}{d-Z}Y
\end{equation}

As a matrix equation this may be re-written

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{d}{d-Z}&0&0\\
0&\frac{d}{d-Z}&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
X\\Y\\Z
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}